# C++ nested classes referencing each other

Tags: c++, class, nested, visual-studio-2017

In C# I can have two nested classes refer to each other without problem:

```
public class CFGFile
{
  class Setting
  {
    public Entry Ent;
  }

  class Entry
  {
    public Setting Setg;
  }
}
```

However, trying the same thing in C++ causes problems:

```
class CFGFile
{
  class Setting;

  class Entry
  {
    Setting Setg;
  };

  class Setting
  {
    Entry Ent;
  ]
};
```

I get

> "incomplete type not allowed"

at the Setg variable definition, and error

> "C2079: 'CFGFile::Entry::Setg' uses undefined class
>   'CFGFile::Setting'"

when compiling.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Is cross referring not possible in nested classes in C++?

Comment: Try with struct instead of class in C#, this should be a fair comparison. Shouldn't work either.

Comment: @tkausl because in the C# example above, references to objects are being defined, not objects of the class types. I get it. Thanks!

Comment: values cannot be `NULL`, so what you wrote is a `Entry` containing a `Setting` which in turn contains an `Entry` which again contains a `Setting` which in turn contains an `Entry`.... ad infinitum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `nested` or not. In C++, you can not cross reference each other for two classes/structs like that. The workaround is that you use either pointer or reference which does not require a complete type definition. In your case, try the following,

```
class CFGFile
{
  class Setting;

  class Entry
  {
    Setting* Setg;  // or std::unique_ptr<Setting> Setg;
  };

  class Setting
  {
    Entry Ent;
  };
};
```

As suggested by @Ted Lyngmo, `std::unique_ptr` is the preferred way in modern C++ for applications.

Comment: Perhaps a suggestion to use `std::unique_ptr<Setting> Setg;` would be good.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on why this happens, this comes from the fact that when the compiler looks at a struct or class, it needs to be able to determine its exact size, among other things to be able to know how much memory it needs to allocate for instances of these.

In this case, the compiler can't determine the size of `Entry` because it only knows that a `Setting` class exists, but it doesn't know its size yet.

Using a pointer, i.e.:

```
class Setting;

class Entry
{
    Setting* Setg;
};
```

actually solves this problem, because while the compiler still doesn't know anything about `Setting`, it still knows the size of a pointer (regardless of the pointee's type).

As already mentioned, the "nested" part has no impact on this.

Answer (score 0):

C# - by design - uses reference semantics for classes, thus the provided snippet does not cause circular value depency. OTH c++ prefers value semantics , which would -in turn- result in infinite recursion in the original sample code, if the standard did not ban that kind of code; As implicated in earlier replies, if reference semantics is needed, it should be explicitly expressed in terms of pointer/reference syntax.